# Create the dot animation of Shazam app

Tags: css, animation, react-native, menu

I want to reproduce the same dot animation as Shazam (when you swipe left/right in their mobile app).

[image]

Do you know the best way to reproduce this kind of animation in React Native ? 
Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: I hear best way to do it is ask on [so]. They just love *zero-effort* questions.

Comment: If you want people to help you, at least make an attempt and post a fiddle.

Comment: Sorrry @AndreiGheorghiu and MrGood, all I wanted was a starting point. But you're right, I will use the stratini answer to try an implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for D3, ART and Lottie.

Comment: Don't you hate people that downvote without explaining why? Me too.